# React native function as parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-native, delegates

How can i pass a function as a parameter in react native?
I am trying something like:

```
 elementExistsInServerList(func) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (func(this.serverList[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

And after that i am trying to call it:

```
var serverWithTheSameServerNameAlreadyExists = this.elementExistsInServerList(function (server) {
        alert(server.serverName);
        return server.serverName == this.state.serverName;
    });
```

But i don't get any alert even if the server list contains 10 elements.

Comment: **It's just a typo.** You wanted `this.serverList.length`, not `this.length`, in your `for` loop condition.

Comment: Side note: That entire function can be replaced with: `return this.serverList.some(func);` More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I didn't know about some function so i tried to implement by myself.